# Why does my recursively-called function not follow through all the iterations?

Tags: java, swing, recursion

I am working on making Minesweeper in Java as a beginner project, and am working on the feature where all the cells around a 0 are selected automatically so the user doesn't have to manually click all the 0-designated cells.

To do this I am trying to recursively call the method to fill out the entire "0 area."

```
private void checkZero(int x, int y) {
    if(countSurroundingMines(mines, x, y) == 0){
        int left = x-1, right = x+1, up = y-1, down = y+1;

    if(x==0){left = x;}
    if(y==0){up = y;}
    if(x==17){right = x;}
    if(y==13){down = y;}

    for(int i = left; i <= right; i++){
        for(int j = up; j <= down; j++){
            clicked[i][j] = true;
            checkZero(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

This code only recurs over the upper left cells, and doesn't complete the for loop. Why?

Comment: It looks like you're going to call `checkZero` on the same square repeatedly until a stack overflow. Do you get any exceptions? Maybe your check zero should check if the square is clicked an return right away so you don't recurse infinitely into the same square?

Comment: shouldn't that algorithm somehow *mark* already visited cells? As written in previous comment, once called with any x,y, it will be called recursively for x,y again directly and indirectly (e.g. checking the left cell and that call checking the right cell of the left one, that is, the same x,y again)

Answer (score 1):

The boundary conditions aren't right, and each call to `checkZero()` will always check `x,y` pairs even if they were already checked.

If you run that code with input like `x=4`, and `y=5` for example, it makes successive calls, decrementing the values of `x` and `y` until they're both 0, then it gets pinned calling the function thousands of times with the same input: `x=0`, `y=0`. There's nothing guarding that `0,0` was just checked.

Here's an example program that:

- uses a data structure (`java.util.Set`) to keep track of which coordinate pairs have been seen before
- each pair is identified crudely as a comma-separated string, so if `i=1` and `j=2`, then we make a unique identifier of "`1,2`"
- checks each new coordinate pair before calling `checkZero()` – has this been seen before? If so, skip it.
- rewrites the logic for setting `left`, `right`, etc. to be defined within the initial assignment
- replaces your boundaries of 0, 17, and 13 with simply 0 and 3 – smaller numeric space, easier to print the sample run here

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Example {

    private static Set<String> pairsChecked;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pairsChecked = new HashSet<>(); // use a new set before checking
        checkZero(1, 2);
    }

    public static void checkZero(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("x=" + x + " y=" + y);

        int left = x <= 0 ? 0 : x - 1;
        int right = x >= 3 ? 3 : x + 1;
        int up = y <= 0 ? 0 : y - 1;
        int down = y >= 3 ? 3 : y + 1;

        for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
            for (int j = up; j <= down; j++) {
                String pair = i + "," + j;
                if (pairsChecked.contains(pair)) {
                    // skip this coordinate pair, we've already seen it
                } else {
                    pairsChecked.add(pair); // take note that we've seen i,j
                    checkZero(i, j);        // then go ahead and check i,j
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's sample output showing that it works, doesn't run forever, and doesn't re-check any pairs:

```
x=1 y=2
x=0 y=1
x=0 y=0
x=1 y=0
x=1 y=1
x=0 y=2
x=0 y=3
x=1 y=2
x=1 y=3
x=2 y=2
x=2 y=1
x=2 y=0
x=3 y=0
x=3 y=1
x=3 y=2
x=2 y=3
x=3 y=3
```